# how to use dictionary to make code tidy in C# for unity scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code for the animator controller in unity, which works fine, but has shown it is just repeating myself over and over to change some variables.
My question is whether there's a way to make a dictionary in C# to make it less repetitive.
I suppose there should be a way but as I am new to c# I would be grateful for the help

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class anim : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Animator animator = null;


    private static readonly int hashHappy = Animator.StringToHash("happy");
    private static readonly int hashSad = Animator.StringToHash("sad");

    
    void Update()
     {
         if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.H))
         {

             animator.SetBool(hashHappy, true);
             animator.SetBool(hashSad, false);

         } else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.H))
         {
             Invoke("finishHappy", 5f);
           
         }

         if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)){

             animator.SetBool(hashHappy, false);
             animator.SetBool(hashSad, true);

         } else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
         {
             Invoke("finishSad", 5f);
           
         }





        

     }

     public void finishHappy()=>animator.SetBool(hashHappy, false);
     public void finishSad()=>animator.SetBool(hashSad, false);

 
        
   


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably be inclined to use a Dictionary as you first thought. And then pair that with some Enums for you expressions. The end result would look something like this:

```
public enum ExpressionType
{
    None,
    Happy,
    Sad,
    Angry,
    // etc. etc.
}

public class anim : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Animator animator = null;

    private static Dictionary<ExpressionType, int> expressions = new Dictionary<ExpressionType, int> ( )
    {
        [ ExpressionType.Happy ] = Animator.StringToHash ( "happy" ),
        [ ExpressionType.Sad ] = Animator.StringToHash ( "sad" ),
        [ ExpressionType.Angry ] = Animator.StringToHash ( "angry" ),
    };

    private static anim _instance;
    private void Awake ( )
    {
        _instance = this;
    }

    public static bool Set ( ExpressionType e = ExpressionType.None )
    {
        if ( _instance ) return false;
        foreach ( var kv in expressions )
            _instance.animator.SetBool ( kv.Value, kv.Key == e );
        return true;
    }

    void Update ( )
    {
        if ( Input.GetKeyDown ( KeyCode.H ) )
            Set ( ExpressionType.Happy );
        else if ( Input.GetKeyUp ( KeyCode.H ) )
            Invoke ( "Set", 5f );

        if ( Input.GetKey ( KeyCode.S ) )
            Set ( ExpressionType.Sad );
        else if ( Input.GetKeyUp ( KeyCode.S ) )
            Invoke ( "Set", 5f );
    }
}
```

Passing no argument to the static `Set` method will force all bool values to be set to false, and that's why calling `Invoke("Set", 5f)` can be used, instead of trying to specify exactly which animator Boolean to set to false.

You could add a separate `Reset` method if you wanted to save a couple of unnecessary calls to the Animator, but it's not going to break anything if you left it as is.

Note that this is really only of benefit if you're using the bool animator value. Setting a trigger or passing values would require `Set` to do some extra data type checks. And a final note to say that I've written but not tested the code. Looks like it should do the trick though.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and code, it works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Fair warning, I have no idea if what you are doing makes sense, as i have limited unity knowledge.

However, the data structure I would use would be a `List<T>`. This would allow you to iterate over it the *hashes* and toggle the *animation*.

**Given**

```
public static class SomeClass
{
   private static readonly int hashHappy = Animator.StringToHash("happy");
   private static readonly int hashClap = Animator.StringToHash("clap");
   private static readonly int hashSad = Animator.StringToHash("sad");
   private static readonly int hashAngry = Animator.StringToHash("angry");
   private static readonly int hashDance = Animator.StringToHash("dance");
   private static readonly int hashDie = Animator.StringToHash("die");

   privatestatic List<int> _hashes;

   static SomeClass()
   {
      _hashes = new List<int>() {hashHappy, hashClap, hashSad, hashAngry, hashDance, hashDie};
   }

   public static void Set(Animator animator, int hash)
   {
      foreach (var item in _hashes)
         animator.SetBool(hash, item == hash);
   }
}
```

**usage**

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.H))
   SomeClass.Set(animator, hashHappy);
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C)) 
   SomeClass.Set(animator, hashClap);
```